# Why did English become a universal language and when?

Tags: history

As we all know, English is the universal communication medium. Now we know how powerful it is to convey our thoughts. When did it become a common language? Why did they opt for this language?

Comment: "Now we know how powerful it is to convey our thoughts."  You don't mean to say that English is more capable than other languages to express a given idea, do you?

Comment: @Kosmonaut I suppose the power of a language is a function of the number of people and nationalities that will understand it. By [that metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_total_number_of_speakers) I suppose English, Spanish and Chinese are the top contenders.

Comment: Note that while the number of people who speak Mandarin is also very large, they are almost all in China. Spanish is spoken in many countries, but besides Spain itself they are almost all in South America. English surely "wins" today as the language understood in the most diverse places.

Comment: Why are "they"?

Comment: There are unsubstantiated presuppositions in the question. It requires to be strengthened or closed as NARQ.

Comment: English will probably became less popular in the next decades when new languages will emerge. It's incredible complicated and illogical when compared with Esperanto, Ido or Slovio. I think that Esperanto or some of its fork will became the new English of the 21st and 22nd century. Maybe with Lojban or I should say .lojban. ;) as the second language (it's too messy and hard to read when in a normal text/article).

Comment: E.g. Spanish it's much easier than English. It's probably the easiest European language to learn. But British were/are better imperialists than Spanish and here you are to,too,two and other crap.

Comment: Nicholas Ostler's book _The Last Lingua Franca_ is a relevant resource here.

Comment: Is English is a universal language? I think that is an overstatement because 70% of the worlds population speaks other languages. Chinese is the most spoken language in the world in terms of people who speak it as mother tongue and Spanish is the second.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

English became the *[lingua franca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_franca)* around WWII, but it was already used all through the British Colonial Empire, establishing it in North America and Australia among others. here is a citation of Wikipedia:

> It[English] has
>   replaced French as the lingua franca
>   of diplomacy since World War II. The
>   rise of English in diplomacy began in
>   1919, in the aftermath of World War I,
>   when the Treaty of Versailles  was
>   written in English as well as in
>   French, the dominant language used in
>   diplomacy until that time. The
>   widespread use of English was further
>   advanced by the prominent
>   international role played by
>   English-speaking nations (the United
>   States and the Commonwealth of
>   Nations) in the aftermath of World War
>   II, particularly in the establishment
>   and organization of the United
>   Nations. 
> [...]
>  When the United Kingdom
>   became a colonial power, English
>   served as the lingua franca of the
>   colonies of the British Empire. In the
>   post-colonial period, some of the
>   newly created nations which had
>   multiple indigenous languages  opted
>   to continue using English as the
>   lingua franca to avoid the political
>   difficulties inherent in promoting any
>   one indigenous language above the
>   others. The British Empire established
>   the use of English in regions around
>   the world such as North America,
>   India, Africa, Australia and New
>   Zealand, so that by the late 19th
>   century its reach was truly global, 
>   and in the latter half of the 20th
>   century, widespread international use
>   of English was much reinforced by the
>   global economic, financial,
>   scientific, military, and cultural
>   pre-eminence of the English-speaking
>   countries and especially the U.S.
>   Today, more than half of all
>   scientific journals are published in
>   English, while in France, almost one
>   third of all natural science research
>   appears in English, lending some
>   support to English being the lingua
>   franca of science and technology.
>   English is also the lingua franca of
>   international Air Traffic Control
>   communications.

Comment: Ah, the irony of calling English the "lingua franca": a Latin phrase meaning "French Language".

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New: [I fail to see the irony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Origins_of_English_PieChart.svg) :-)))

Comment: hm why isn't english considered a romance language if the majority of its words come from Latin and French? Perhaps that chart isn't scaled by frequency of word use, which might be more useful.

Comment: @Claudiu: the vocabulary may be largely from romance languages, but the grammar is germanic.

Comment: I've read that short Anglo-Saxon words may be a minority of the vocabulary but they are the most used.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: As with most languages the words that stay through the aeons tend to be the basic words used everyday, simple nouns and verbs.  The more complex stuff is a lot more subject to competition from foreign invaders.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny: I think it's rather illustrative that english has adopted *lingua franca* while France has an official agency tasked with keeping anglicisms out of french. *Viva email!*

Comment: @Wayne - wouldn't that be "Vive l'email?"

Comment: @MT_Head: Sounds much more accurate, though I believe that that officially, the French are supposed to say *courriel* instead of *email*.

Comment: @Wayne: you are talking about the _[Quebecker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec)_ (French Canadian), and maybe the _[Wallons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belgium)_.

Comment: @Eldros: Yes, *courriel* came from Quebec, but it was officially designated by France's Cultural Ministry as the replacement for the evil *email* that had crept into France. I believe the dictate only has legal force over government agencies and is widely ignored, but the mere fact that a government agency would attempt to do this is amazing to me.

Comment: @Wayne: That's the _[Académie Française](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise)_ for you.

Comment: Mr. Shiny and New 安宇: Forgive the pedantry, but we need to put a stop to this canard. *lingua franca* is actually Italian for *the Frankish language*.  The Franks were a Germanic group.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 [That is False](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_franca#Etymology)

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 The mere notion that Latin had a word meaning ‘French’ is, if you think about it, nonsensical. France did not exist in Roman times—indeed, the French language is descendent to Latin, which means Latin _cannot_ have had a word for it, just like Old English did not have a word for American English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Don't forget that Latin was revived in the Middle Ages. And people still coin Latin words today. Are those words not "Latin" just because Caesar wouldn't have recognized it? If not, what are they? In any case, the Romans had a word for the Franks and their language.

Comment: 20 points for pasting something off wikipedia?

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇, no, I’d say they’re words in the languages they’re coined in, not in Latin. Latin was a living, natural language—it is not spoken as such anymore. What we coin now are English (or French, Spanish, etc.) words based on Latin words. And yes, they had a word for the _Franks_. But not for the French. :-)

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew Are modern, technical terms of the english language proper english words? Shakespeare surely wouldn't understand many words of modern english. Languages evolve.

Answer (score 13):

This is a difficult question to answer because so many of the terms are vague. Even the term "English" is mutable, as there are many dialects and variants used regionally which are quite distinct from one another, with their own grammatical quirks and entirely unique vocabularies.

However, I would say that it was England's massive colonial expansion and the post-colonial retention of English for trade and negotiation that are mostly responsible for it's prevalence - in turn caused by England's naval superiority for many centuries. The aggressively prolific production of English-language media in the early- to mid-twentieth century (Hollywood et al) resulted in prolonged global exposure, and a significant proportion of research and diplomacy was already taking place in English. Nobody can say exactly when its usage gained "critical mass," but I would agree that it was somewhere in the early 20th century.

There are many other universal-communication languages in use (a notable drive in S E Asia to promote "Mandarin" Chinese as a *lingua franca* is underway) but as you say, none of them so prevalent as English.

Comment: To nitpick: it should be "the United Kingdom" (from 1707; "Great Britain" before then) rather than "England" when talking about the Empire.

Comment: Ach, it's a fair point, but a contentious one. That's a debate I'll avoid, I think...!

Comment: (To nitpick further: in my earlier comment, the year should be 1801).

Comment: @Steve Melnikoff: Come on Steve, get your acts of union right! ;-)

Comment: If you don't want to be controversial, how come the Empire and trade were "caused by" naval superiority and not its causes?

Answer (score 10):

I am very surprised that none of the answers has mentioned the obvious: English is *simple*. Speaking English at the basic level needed to order a meal or direct a taxi is far easier than any other language I know. Speaking English well is another matter entirely, but the *lingua franca* does not require great ability.

English has the following features that make it very easy to speak it well enough to be understood:

- No gendered nouns. Compare to any Latin language, for example.
- No declinations. Compare to German or Greek.
- The conjugation of the overwhelming majority of verbs is trivial, almost non-existent. For example compare the verb *to find*, in English and French:

  ```
  I find                     je trouve
  You find                   tu trouves  
  He/She finds               il/elle trouve       
  We find                    nous trouvons  
  You find                   vous trouvez  
  They find                  ils/elles trouvent
  ```

  In English, only the third person singular changes and that by a single character. This is the case for most verbs.
- No infinitive, the name of the verb is the same as the verb itself with an added *to*. For example, the verb *to go* (first person singular *I go*). Compare to, say, Spanish, where the verb is *ir* and the first person singular is *yo voy*. Let alone french where the first person singular of *aller*  is *je vais*.
- English, like all European languages, uses a phonetic alphabet. This will make it much easier for foreigners to learn since there are only 26 letters (in English), unlike languages like Chinese where writing requires the memorization of hundreds of characters.
- English has no accents.

Now, I want to stress that the chaotic nature of English makes it a very difficult language to speak well. However, its basic simplicity makes it a very easy language to speak just well enough to be understood. I think that this is a very important factor to consider when thinking of the language's current popularity.

Obviously the historical, geopolitical and economic considerations mentioned in the other answers play a major role. Greek has none of these points in its favor yet was the *lingua franca* of the Byzantine world for centuries. Simplicity is not essential for a language to become widely spoken but it does help.

Comment: You're cheating with *ir* and *aller*. The corresponding verbs in English are "to be" and "to go", and their past tenses are "I was" and "I went". No simpler than the Spanish or French versions. And the accents in Spanish and French make the pronunciation closer to the spelling ... a big drawback of English. I'd say having them is an advantage for these languages.

Comment: @PeterShor no they're not, _go_ is _ir_ and _aller_ respectively. They are only _to be_ if used to construct tenses which is not what I am talking about. In any case, English verbs very rarely change from the "infinitive" to the first person singular which is my main point. Do you disagree that English is a particularly easy language to speak at a basic level? As for spelling, Spanish spelling is _exactly_ what you hear 99% of the time (and the accent never affects spelling). French spelling is all over the place. Admittedly, so is English spelling but that's why I don't mention it.

Comment: If the official language of the USA were German, today we'd all be speaking about  its grammar being so logical and how phonetic its is. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/about-the-german-language. If the US's official language was French we'd be musing about its musicality and importance in the field of art, literature and politics. And if the US's official language was Italian, we'd all be talking about how great Italian pizzas are and how Latin brought civilization/culture to the barbaric world.

Comment: @Mari-LouA what's your point? I never claimed English grammar is logical! I'm sure you agree it is anything but. My point is simply that speaking English *at a basic level* is very easy for the reasons outlined above. Of course the geopolitical dominance of English-speaking countries is a huge factor here, all I'm saying is that the simplicity of basic English is also relevant.

Comment: You're saying people are choosing English because of its simplicity, I'm disputing your introductory line: *I am very surprised that none of the answers has mentioned the obvious: English is simple.* Its spelling, pronunciation, phrasal verbs, slang, idiomatic expressions are far from being simple. To reach a certain level of communicability can be relatively easy to obtain, but to become proficient requires hard work. We could well be talking about mandarin being the second lingua franca in 50 years time.

Comment: @Mari-LouA please read the second sentence as well: *Speaking English **at the basic level** needed to order a meal . . .*. I also dedicate the last two paragraphs to the fact that English is extremely hard to master and that simplicity is not enough to make a language dominant. However, basic English is indeed very simple and that is one of the reasons for its popularity. I'm not talking about proficiency here, only about basic communication.

Comment: And I am surprised that the "obvious" reason why English has become the lingua franca is not apparent to you. I know many Italian speakers who have said they preferred studying Spanish because it is easier. And I suspect the majority of Spanish speakers would say Italian, and French are simpler to learn. Scandinavian speakers (Danes, Fins etc.) seem to take to English like a duck to water. But I'm not sure the same could be said for Arabic speakers, maybe they prefer French for obvious geopolitical reasons. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I never said it was *the* reason. I only said it was *a* reason, in addition to the obvious geopolitical ones. I thought, perhaps mistakenly, that the two final paragraphs of my answer make that clear. All I'm saying is that English has certain characteristics that make it a relatively simple language to learn at the basic level.

Comment: I think, the globally spread simple english, is something akin to Vulgar Latin, whereas well-spoken (I can't think of the opposite of *simple english*) could be viewed as the analogue of Classical Latin. In the Roman Empire, the Romans spoke Latin, as the Empire expanded a lot of non-Romans adopted Latin, which underwent significant simpification in the process. I read in a book in the origins of the english language the term *Legionary's Latin* referring to the simplified Latin of the legionaries, whose mother tongue wasn't Latin.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with the other answers which emphasize: a) the British empire, and b) the dominance of the US in business/science in the post-WWII era. I might also add that its simple alphabet (non-calligraphic, no accents, etc) was very useful in the early computer era when coding and printers were simple.

On a biased note, it's my impression that English is more dynamic than many languages (quick to adopt foreign words and to coin phrases), and while it has a lot of irregular verbs it has also undergone trade-language-like simplifications, such as the dropping of noun gender and less inflection. I've been told that english has more synonyms than some languages, which also makes rhyming easy. Last, perhaps the US's history of immigration also helped spread exposure.

Answer (score 5):

Usually the nation with the biggest power spreads its culture and language. Take the Greeks or Romans for example, when they were in power, the world spoke their language. As simple as that.

Answer (score 3):

Not really related, but I couldn't resist:

> It's not that they're wicked or
>   naturally bad
>   It's knowing they're
>   foreign that makes them so mad
>   The
>   English are all that a nation should
>   be
>   And the pride of the English are
>   Donald and me
>
> The English the English the English are best
>     I wouldn't give tuppence for all of the rest

Full lyrics [here](http://sniff.numachi.com/pages/tiTHENGLSH.html).

**EDIT** On a slightly more serious vote (erm, freudian slip, I meant *note*!), I think that apart from the geopolitical aspect, another element in the success of English is its flexibility and openness to evolution.

If you contrast with a protectionist language like French that has a 'magisterium' which has to decide on all things new (*l'Académie Française*), there is much less liberty to improvise or adapt. In English, it's often been a case of 'If you can't beat them, join them', and we liberally import any new and useful words we come across.

So in one sense, English hasn't so much beaten other languages as absorbed them.

Comment: @Rhodri, yes, I wasn't too sure but it was the first link I came across and my memories were hazy. If you've got a better version, I'll update.

Comment: Resistance is futile, you will be assimilated.

Comment: What's delightful is that English is do lassez-faire about adding new words that you can actually [invent a new language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boontling) by speaking English in a slightly different context.

Answer (score 3):

The BBC News magazine has an article on "[How English evolved into a global language](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-12017753)"

> As the British Library charts the evolution of English in a new major exhibition, author Michael Rosen gives a brief history of a language that has grown to world domination with phrases such as "cool" and "go to it".

It refers to a free exhibition at the British Library: "[Evolving English - One Language, Many Voices](http://www.bl.uk/evolvingenglish/reviews.html)"

Comment: This answer basically consists one good link and a dead one (404 - page not found on www.bl.uk).