# Is English considered easier to learn than most of the other languages in the world?

Tags: grammaticality, history, early-modern-english, old-english, learning

In comparison to the other languages, I think English is much more simpler. For example, compared to French, English nouns have no gender, adjectives have only one form and verbs have extremely simple conjugations.  I'm wondering if there is a historical reason behind it. Has there been any scholarly research about the relative ease of learning the world's major languages, and if so, how does English compare to the others?

Comment: You may think it, but millions will disagree (even with your examples; e.g. adjectives do not inflect for case but they can for degree). And I would expect a speaker of Catalonian, say, to pick up French more readily than English due to their similar grammars. Any answer will be too broad or too opinion-based to be answerable here. The global use of English is [attributable](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/5831) to forces of history and economics (the British Empire, Pax Americana, Hollywood, etc.), not because English is so easy (or, for that matter, so beautiful, expressive, or logical).

Comment: @choster You mean Catalan.

Comment: @tchrist Quite so. The original version of the comment used nationalities, but I thought it would be less political to use languages. And is usually the case with such efforts, my inattentive editing ensures that no one is satisfied now.

Comment: @choster I can think of absolutely no other sentence apart from this one in which I would ever, **ever** say *∗Catalonian*.  In all others, please use *Catalan*.

Comment: It's not even clear to me that French is more complicated than English. I think the maximum number of forms for a French verb in the indicative case is 10, for etre (counting only the phonetically distinct forms), and the 1st person plural form is less commonly used nowadays. English "to be" has 8 forms. So French does have more inflection here. But English has a fair number of irregular verbs, and also phrasal verbs. French has gender, but for the vast majority of nouns the singular and plural forms sound the same. As choster pointed out, English has adjectives that can inflect for degree.

Comment: Overall, I'd say French is probably more inflectionally complex than English, but that's not all there is to difficulty!

Comment: @sumelic To me French is indeed more complicated than English. Before I say a French sentence I have to make sure everything, like the gender, the number, the conjugation is ok.  But as for English, I can speak as I think.   BTW, neither of them is my mother tongue.

Comment: Comparing English to French, is like comparing (English) learning how to use a yo-yo, or maybe a frisbee to (French) gaining a law degree.  English is by far the world's "loosest" language.

Comment: Vim, this  a great question. (The fact that it is closed just reflects on the usual voting hilariousness on this site, so don't worry about it.)  (1) before the rise of China, English was the "lingua franca" of the world for a good 100+ years and subsequently has many messy forms (2) during the 20th century, culture **became extremely populist** - we all celebrated and embraced anti-intellectualism (3) pop music (which is all-but primarily English) is a massive storehouse of memetic English

Comment: It is relatively easy to reach a pre-intermediate level in English, in other words you can achieve simple communicative tasks by knowing the basic rules of construction (grammar) and learning its vocabulary. It is MUCH harder to reach proficiency level, and then you seem to dismiss the pronounciation aspect. For many Romance speakers, the English language is a *hard* beast to pronounce.

Comment: I agree that the question is interesting, and I'm sure that we would hear many valid *opinions*, (not answers) but the question is, realistically speaking, too vast.

Comment: Would that English were simple :)

Comment: @PhilMJones. To reach an intermediate level is no hard task.  But proficiency is another story. Just as the comments above show.

Comment: @Vim Indeed.  I was being silly.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - It might be hard to pronounce, but first most English speakers enjoy a romance-speaker's accented mispronunciation, and English has more than a few variant pronunciations anyway.  So fire away, you cant' be worse than a Boston or Cockney accent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It started out as a pidgin, a simplified version of Anglo-Saxon that Norse invaders could understand. Anglo-saxon was(is) highly inflected, "the king gives horses to his men" can be written in many different ways. "king giveth horses", "horses are giventh by king" "by king horses givening"  (Not really Anglo-saxon but you get the idea).

Now imagine you are a Norseman who knows the words, `horse`, `give` and `king` (because your language is also Germanic) but you can't pick up the endings. You have no idea who gave what to who. So if you are trying to buy cows from a farmer you need to simplify it to "me give you money, you give me cows".

Then after the Norman conquest all the people who cared about grammatical rules and correct language (monks, poets, grade-school teachers) spoke Latin or French, leaving English to be spoken by the normal people. Who just dropped complicated inflections when they couldn't remember them, or the most common endings were applied to all cases. Sometimes irregular endings have been kept as modern plurals simply because that was the most common usage.

Today, although the spelling is a bit random, English is easy to understand because it is so highly redundant. There are many ways to say the same thing, so even if you might not get a phrase exactly correct (to EL&U standards) you will be likely to be understood. In languages with a much more grammatical structure, where who is doing what to who (or whom?) is based solely on a suffix that is easy to get wrong - it is much more difficult to be understood.

Comment: The theory that English went through a pidgin stage is far from accepted, so I wouldn't present it as a fact like you're doing here.  English preserved ablaut in verbs and nouns, and still has widespread inflection for past tense, 3rd-person singular and noun plurals. It may be simpler in morphology than some other European languages, but it's not as simple as a creole and shows no signs of ever having been.

Comment: Also, you don't seem to understand how a pidgin works. "Normal people" don't forget the rules of their own language, even if all the "people who care about grammatical rules" go away. For a native speaker of a language with cases or gender, remembering the inflections is no more complicated than it is for us modern speakers of English to remember that 3rd person singular verbs end in -s. It's automatic, it doesn't take effort! Languages get simplified as a result of contact where people who **don't know the language** try to use it, and fail to learn it perfectly.

Comment: @sumelic So you don't feel that many people today have forgotten the difference between lay/lain or who/whom ?

Comment: @sumelic - this is different from a pidgin. If you are a Anglo Saxon trying to trade with a Dane you can't base who is paying who on a noun declension. You need to say "you give money, me give cows".

Comment: You can find plenty of people today who care very much about rules like when to use "lay" and "lain" or when to use "who" and "whom". But despite these peevers, normal people will speak the way that comes naturally to them. The grade-school teachers and others like this simply don't have much of an effect on language at the basic level that we're talking about. "This is different from a pidgin" -- What's the "this" here?

Comment: I actually agree in part with your answer, but I think it's oversimplified to the point of being misleading. It is true that maintaining a standardized, literary language requires knowledgeable people to use it, like these monks poets etc. But the differences between standardized and un-standardized languages are not always of the form "unstandardized speech drops inflections". In Germany, there are a lot of unstandardized dialects, but I believe these still retain case. There's some valuable discussion at the following page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Middle_English_creole_hypothesis

Comment: Basically, I'd like to see something like your explanation of the Anglo-Saxon and the Dane in your answer -- something about how oral contact between speakers of different languages, not just the loss of a written tradition, is a likely cause of the simplification of noun endings that occurred in English.

Comment: @sumelic - I expanded it a bit.  I think pidgin is a reasonable explanation for Old English and the French/Latin effect for Middle (although this is a bit more dubious)

Comment: Your argument seems to largely be based around the fact that, the majority of the time the majority of speakers of English were common people. Except, of course, the issue with that is it's true of every living language. Most people, anywhere, aren't grammarians. His original question is "is learning English *easier* than learning *other languages*?", which your answer kind of sidesteps.

Comment: You chose bad examples of Scando-words there: _horse_ would be almost unrecognisable (_hestr_ being the normal Norse word), and _give_ is more Norse than English anyway. The endings also fairly similar in ON and OE and wouldn't have caused much trouble. And it's no harder to be understood in highly inflected languages than in more analytic ones: native speakers understand you perfectly well even though you mess up the grammar.

Comment: And furthermore, the developments you describe (things like dropping desinences, losing distinctions between things like lay/lain and who/whom, etc.) are constantly happening in every single language in the world. It's a natural part of Dixon’s cycle, and it has nothing to do with pidgins or people needing to trade with foreigners.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I was tryign to think of something Anglo-saxonish. The king can give iPhones to his men if you prefer.